# How to boot into Linux on a regular basis with a grub that has Windows as the default?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

In a PC using Windows, I'd like to schedule a boot into Linux every x days (alternatively every x bootstraps).
Is there a way to have Grub2 make this timed, *cron-like*, boot?

Answer (score 0):

You could just set up a schedule in windows to reboot whenever you want and configure grub to default boot into ubuntu.

Comment: As per the title, Windows has to boot as the default in that PC.